# Calling getResolvedOptions() in Local Environment Generates KeyError

Tags: python, aws-glue, traceback

I have a local AWS Glue environment with the AWS Glue libraries, Spark, PySpark, and everything installed.

I'm running the following code (literally copy-past in the REPL):

```py
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = []
args.insert(-1, {"--JOB_NAME": "JOB_NAME"})
args.insert(-1, {"--input_file_path": "s3://things/that.csv"})
args.insert(-1, {"--output_bucket": "s3://things"})

getResolvedOptions(args, [
    '--JOB_NAME',
    '--input_file_path',
    '--output_bucket']
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\UBI9\bin\aws-glue-libs\PyGlue.zip\awsglue\utils.py", line 115, in getResolvedOptions
  File "C:\Progra~1\Python37\lib\argparse.py", line 1781, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Progra~1\Python37\lib\argparse.py", line 1822, in _parse_known_args
    option_tuple = self._parse_optional(arg_string)
  File "C:\Progra~1\Python37\lib\argparse.py", line 2108, in _parse_optional
    if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
KeyError: 0
```

The value of `args` is as follows:

```py
[{'--input_file_path': 's3://things/that.csv'}, {'--output_bucket': 's3://things'}, {'--JOB_NAME': 'JOB_NAME'}]
```

When I pull up [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html) it looks like `args` is a list of arguments. I'd assumed it was a list of key-value pairs. Is that wrong? Can I not run this function locally?

Comment: Can you rename args to some thing else and try again?

Comment: I get the same result with that scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html), `--JOB_NAME` is internal to AWS Glue and you should not set it.

If you're running a local Glue setup and wish to run the job locally, you can pass the `--JOB_NAME` parameter when the job is submitted to [gluesparksubmit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-python). E.g.

```
./bin/gluesparksubmit path/to/job.py --JOB_NAME=my-job --input_file_path='s3://path'
```

And access the arguments

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'input_file_path'])
print(args['JOB_NAME'])
print(args['input_file_path'])
```

Comment: Problem is/was the value of `args` needed to be a list of strings including the JOB_NAME assignment e.g., `argv = ['whatevs', '--JOB_NAME=ThisIsMySickJobName']`. Once I made that change, everything just worked. In my example, each element in the list was a key/value pair.

Comment: That said, your answer will work. I appreciate the time. I'll mark this correct.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with my code was how I'd expressed the JOB_NAME assignment. I'd been adding a key/value pair to the list. The code was expecting a "--KEY=VALUE" string:

```py
argv = ['whatevs', '--JOB_NAME=ThisIsMySickJobName']
```

Running the following worked just fine...

```py
from pprint import pprint as pp
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
argv = ['whatevs', '--JOB_NAME=ThisIsMySickJobName']
args = getResolvedOptions(argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
pp(args)
```

Here's the money shot...

[image]